# How to get an identity for NEPacketTunnelProvider Networkextension from keychain?

Tags: ios, swift, keychain, networkextension

I am working on an Networkextension using NEPacketTunnelProvider. I am using a configuration profile with com.apple.vpn.managed payload. Furthermore, I use ClientCertificate authentication with an com.apple.security.pkcs12 payload. According to [NETunnelProviderManager](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/networkextension/netunnelprovidermanager#1661706) documentation it should be possible for my extension to retrieve this identity using the com.apple.managed.vpn.shared keychain access group.

If I query the Keychain for the identity, I always get error code `-25300`. According to [www.osstatus.com](https://www.osstatus.com/search/results?platform=all&framework=all&search=-25300) this means: "The item cannot be found."

Code 1:
I try to use the persistent reference provided by the protocolConfiguration to retrieve the identity.

```
class PacketTunnelProvider: NEPacketTunnelProvider {

    override func startTunnel(options: [String : NSObject]?, completionHandler: @escaping (Error?) -> Void) {

        NSLog("vpn-service startTunnel")

        let pc = self.protocolConfiguration
        NSLog("vpn-service protocolConfiguration " + pc.debugDescription)
        if let identity = pc.identityReference {
            let persistentRef = identity as NSData
            NSLog("vpn-service persistentRef "  + persistentRef.description)
            var copyResult: AnyObject?
            let copyErr = SecItemCopyMatching([
                kSecValuePersistentRef as String: persistentRef,
                kSecReturnData as String: true
                ] as CFDictionary, &copyResult)
            NSLog("vpn-service getCert copyErr "  + copyErr.description)
        }
    }
}
```

Output is:

```
Jul 27 10:07:53 Tims-iPhone vpn(libswiftFoundation.dylib)[4994] <Notice>: vpn-service startTunnel
Jul 27 10:07:53 Tims-iPhone vpn(libswiftFoundation.dylib)[4994] <Notice>: vpn-service protocolConfiguration
    type = plugin
    identifier = 3B39941E-AF39-45CE-B869-68AF392FBCA0
    serverAddress = DEFAULT
    password = {
        domain = user
        accessGroup = com.apple.managed.vpn.shared
    }
    identity = {
        identifier = <Subject Name Common Name of the identity installed by the com.apple.security.pkcs12 payload>
        persistentReference = <69646e74 00000000 00000011>
        domain = user
    }
    identityDataImported = NO
    identityReference = <69646e74 00000000 00000011>
    proxySettings = {
        autoProxyDiscovery = NO
        autoProxyConfigurationEnabled = NO
        HTTPEnabled = NO
        HTTPSEnabled = NO
        FTPEnabled = NO
        SOCKSEnabled = NO
        RTSPEnabled = NO
        gopherEnabled = NO
        excludeSimpleHostnames = NO
                usePassiveFTP = YES
    }
    disconnectOnSleep = NO
    disconnectOnIdle = NO
    disconnectOnIdleTimeout = 0
    disconnectOnWake = NO
    disconnectOnWakeTimeout = 0
    pluginType = <my-bundle-id>
    authenticationMethod = 1
Jul 27 10:07:53 Tims-iPhone vpn(libswiftFoundation.dylib)[4994] <Notice>: vpn-service persistentRef <69646e74 00000000 00000011>
Jul 27 10:07:53 Tims-iPhone vpn(libswiftFoundation.dylib)[4994] <Notice>: vpn-service getCert copyErr -25300
```

Code 2:
If I try to retrieve all identitys without the reference, I get `-25300` too.

```
let getQuery: [String: Any] = [
    kSecClass as String: kSecClassIdentity,
    kSecMatchLimit as String: kSecMatchLimitAll,
    kSecReturnAttributes as String: true,
]

var item: CFTypeRef?
let status = SecItemCopyMatching(getQuery as CFDictionary, &item)
NSLog("vpn-service status: " + status.description)
```

I rechecked that the build result got the keychain access group:

codesign -d --ent :- build/Debug-iphoneos/agent.app/PlugIns/vpn.appex/

```
Executable=/Users/timb/projects/xcode/ios-client/build/Debug-iphoneos/agent.app/PlugIns/vpn.appex/vpn
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>application-identifier</key>
    <string><my-application-identifier-of-the-network-extension></string>
    <key>com.apple.developer.networking.networkextension</key>
    <array/>
    <key>com.apple.developer.team-identifier</key>
    <string><my-team-identifier></string>
    <key>get-task-allow</key>
    <true/>
    <key>keychain-access-groups</key>
    <array>
        <string><my-team-identifier>.com.apple.managed.vpn.shared</string>
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

**How to get an identity for NEPacketTunnelProvider Networkextension from keychain?**

Comment: Hi...Did you find the reason?

Comment: Unfortunately, not yet

Comment: Is this applicable in case of `password` of `NEProxyServer`? Have you tried to set password for proxy servers (NEProxyServer)?

Comment: Hey, no I haven't tried. This is necessary if you need to access the com.apple.managed.vpn.shared keychain group. How did you add your password to the configuration profile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will answer myself, because I solved the problem:

1: You need a special entitlement to access the com.apple.managed.vpn.shared group. Create a TSI to get it. This will take about a month. https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/67613 #9

2: Make sure your container app and network extension have the entitlement set. You can check with `codesign -d --entitlements :- <filename>`

It should look like this:

```
<key>keychain-access-groups</key>
<array>
    <string>com.apple.managed.vpn.shared</string>
</array>
```

I am using XCode 10 Beta and there is a problem when you use the GUI. It sets the value like `<string>$(AppIdentifierPrefix)com.apple.managed.vpn.shared</string>`
You have to fix it with a texteditor.

3: Access the data from the keychain. I will post some example code to use the data as base64 encoded strings.

```
guard let identityReference = protocolConfiguration.identityReference else {
    throw ConfigError.errorIdentityNotFound
}
let query: [String : Any] = [
    kSecValuePersistentRef as String: identityReference as CFData,
    kSecReturnRef as String: true,
]

var copyResult: AnyObject?
SecItemCopyMatching(query as CFDictionary, &copyResult)

guard let existingCopyResult = copyResult else {
    throw ConfigError.errorIdentityNotFound
}
let identity = existingCopyResult as! SecIdentity

var certificate: SecCertificate!
SecIdentityCopyCertificate(identity, &certificate)

let DERCertificate = SecCertificateCopyData(certificate) as NSData
let DERCertificateStringBase64Encoded = DERCertificate.base64EncodedString(options: NSData.Base64EncodingOptions.lineLength64Characters)

let PEMCertificateString = "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----\n\(DERCertificateStringBase64Encoded)\n-----END CERTIFICATE-----" 

var privateKey: SecKey!
SecIdentityCopyPrivateKey(identity, &privateKey)
let privateKeyData = SecKeyCopyExternalRepresentation(privateKey, nil) as! NSData
let privateKeyDataBase64Encoded = privateKeyData.base64EncodedString(options: NSData.Base64EncodingOptions.lineLength64Characters)
let privateKeyPKCS1String = "-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----\n\(privateKeyDataBase64Encoded)\n-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----"
```